# Forms authentication: disable redirect to the login page

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have an application that uses ASP.NET Forms Authentication. For the most part, it's working great, but I'm trying to add support for a simple API via an .ashx file. I want the ashx file to have optional authentication (i.e. if you don't supply an Authentication header, then it just works anonymously). But, depending on what you do, I want to require authentication under certain conditions.

I thought it would be a simple matter of responding with status code 401 if the required authentication was not supplied, but it seems like the Forms Authentcation module is intercepting that and responding with a redirect to the login page instead. What I mean is, if my `ProcessRequest` method looks like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 401;
    Response.StatusDescription = "Authentication required";
}
```

Then instead of getting a 401 error code on the client, like I expect, I'm *actually* getting a 302 redirect to the login page.

For nornal HTTP traffic, I can see how that would be useful, but for my API page, I want the 401 to go through unmodified so that the client-side caller can respond to it programmatically instead.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

ASP.NET 4.5 added the Boolean [`HttpResponse.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.suppressformsauthenticationredirect.aspx) property.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 401;
    Response.StatusDescription = "Authentication required";
    Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer for anyone using .NET 4.5. Too bad I didn't read this far in the list and I had to find this on my own in the decompiled sources!

Comment: You can put this in the Global.asax `Application_EndRequest` event to apply this across your entire application. [For Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18519725/188246)

Comment: I used a similar snippet in the Application_BeginRequest method with great success. Is the request AJAX? Set the flag immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I'm marking this as the accepted answer now, since this definitely looks like the way to go now.

Comment: finding this useful in a migration from FormsAuth to ASP.NET Identity where I need both active at the same time

Answer (score 37):

After a bit of investigation, it looks like the [FormsAuthenticationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.aspx) adds a handler for the `HttpApplicationContext.EndRequest` event. In it's handler, it checks for a 401 status code and basically does a `Response.Redirect(loginUrl)` instead. As far as I can tell, there's no way to override this behaviour if want to use `FormsAuthenticationModule`.

The way I ended up getting around it was by disabling the `FormsAuthenticationModule` in the web.config like so:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

And then implementing the `Application_AuthenticateEvent` myself:

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.User == null)
    {
        var oldTicket = ExtractTicketFromCookie(Context, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
        if (oldTicket != null && !oldTicket.Expired)
        {
            var ticket = oldTicket;
            if (FormsAuthentication.SlidingExpiration)
            {
                ticket = FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(oldTicket);
                if (ticket == null)
                    return;
            }

            Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(ticket), new string[0]);
            if (ticket != oldTicket)
            {
                // update the cookie since we've refreshed the ticket
                string cookieValue = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                var cookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] ??
                             new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookieValue) { Path = ticket.CookiePath };

                if (ticket.IsPersistent)
                    cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                cookie.Value = cookieValue;
                cookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL;
                cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
                    cookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
                Context.Response.Cookies.Remove(cookie.Name);
                Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static FormsAuthenticationTicket ExtractTicketFromCookie(HttpContext context, string name)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = null;
    string encryptedTicket = null;

    var cookie = context.Request.Cookies[name];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        encryptedTicket = cookie.Value;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedTicket))
    {
        try
        {
            ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encryptedTicket);
        }
        catch
        {
            context.Request.Cookies.Remove(name);
        }

        if (ticket != null && !ticket.Expired)
        {
            return ticket;
        }

        // if the ticket is expired then remove it
        context.Request.Cookies.Remove(name);
        return null;
    }
}
```

It's actually slightly more complicated than that, but I basically got the code by looking at the implementation of `FormsAuthenticationModule` in reflector. My implementation is different to the built-in `FormsAuthenticationModule` in that it doesn't do anything if you respond with a 401 - no redirecting to the login page at all. I guess if that ever becomes a requirement, I can put an item in the context to disable the auto-redirect or something.

Comment: Note: the [answer by zacharydl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16846041/241462) above is the way to go in ASP.NET 4.5+

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if this will work for everyone, but in IIS7 you can call Response.End() after you've set the status code and description. This way, that #&$^#@*! FormsAuthenticationModule won't do a redirect.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    Response.StatusCode = 401;
    Response.StatusDescription = "Authentication required";
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Nice one John! Isn't it ridiculous how hard we have to work to get around this? HttpContext has a SkipAuthorization property, it would be nice if it had SkipLoginRedirect too. Or if forms authentication could be scoped and overridden by directories.

Comment: When I was trying this out, I was on IIS 6 and I think it works a bit differently for IIS 7 vs IIS 6 (i.e. in IIS 6, `Response.End()` just throws a `ThreadAbortException` which the forms authentication module was catching - meaning it still did the logic redirect for me).

Comment: This works, however control will go to FormsAuthenticationModule anyway and its `EndRequest` event handler will try to do the redirect and since the responce has been `End()`ed, this triggers an exception which is logged in the system event log, also `Application_Error()` is called.

Answer (score 8):

To build on zacharydl's answer slightly, I used this to solve my woes. On every request, at the beginning, if it's AJAX, immediately suppress the behavior.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    HttpRequestBase request = new HttpRequestWrapper(Context.Request);
    if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        Context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how that Response.End() worked for you. I tried it with no joy, then looked at MSDN for Response.End(): 'stops execution of the page, and raises the EndRequest event'.

For what it's worth my hack was:

```
_response.StatusCode = 401;
_context.Items["401Override"] = true;
_response.End();
```

Then in Global.cs add an EndRequest handler (which will get called after Authentication HTTPModule):

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Items["401Override"] != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the page, I used `StatusCode=418` and added the override text to the `StatusDescription`.  Then I captured those in the EndRequest event where I reset the response as you have.  If I use status code 401 in the page it still gets redirected.

Answer (score 4):

what you've found out is correct about the forms auth intercepting the 401 and doing a redirect but we also can do that to reverse that.

Basically what you need is an http module to intercept the 302 redirect to the login page and reverse it to a 401.

Steps on doing that is explained in [here](http://amilagm.com/2010/11/prevent-forms-auth-from-redirecting-to-login-page-in-restful-wcf/)

The given link is about a WCF service but it is the same in all the forms auth scenarios.

**As explained in the above link you need to clear the http headers as well but remember to put the cookie header back to the response if the original response (i.e. before intercepting) contained any cookies.**

Comment: Hmm, yes, that's an interesting idea! Of course, I've already got a solution that works for me, but I'm sure someone else might find this a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a hack likely to have similarly weird side effects!

Answer (score 4):

I know there is already an answer with tick but while trying to solve similar problem I found [this](http://blog.inedo.com/2010/10/12/http-418-im-a-teapot-finally-a-%e2%80%9clegitimate%e2%80%9d-use/) (http://blog.inedo.com/2010/10/12/http-418-im-a-teapot-finally-a-%e2%80%9clegitimate%e2%80%9d-use/) as an alternative.

Basically you return your own HTTP status code (e.g. 418) in your code. In my case a WCF data service.

```
throw new DataServiceException(418, "401 Unauthorized");
```

Then use a HTTP module to handle it at the `EndRequest` event to rewrite the code back to 401.

```
HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
if (app.Context.Response.StatusCode == 418)
{
    app.Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
}
```

The browser / client will receive the correct content and status code, it works great for me :)

If you are interested to learn more about HTTP status code 418 see [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979722/i-am-a-teapot-http-418-status-code).

Comment: Great! It works like I want it to work :) instead adding dedicated http module I used "global.asax" event EndRequest. It is possible to hook on this event overriding "Init" method

Comment: Thanks for mentioning using your own status codes: Since I was only looking to return 401 for a single page that tested authentication via AJAX call, I was able to change the "fail" `Response.StatusCode` on that page to 418 to avoid all the other workarounds! IIS7 complains, but no human would need to visit that page.

Answer (score 2):

That's a known issue, and there's a [NuGet Package](http://nuget.org/packages/aspnet.suppressformsredirect) for that and/or the [source code](http://github.com/johnnyhalife/aspnet.suppressformsredirect) available.

Answer (score 1):

Funny hack if you use.NET Framework >= v4.0 but < v4.5. It uses **reflection** to set value of inaccessible `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` property:

```
// Set property to "true" using reflection
Response
  .GetType()
  .GetProperty("SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect")
  .SetValue(Response, true, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not set the `WWW-Authenticate` header in the code you show, so the client cannot do HTTP authentication instead of forms authentication. If this is the case, you should use 403 instead of 401, which will not be intercepted by the `FormsAuthenticaitonModule`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that I wanted to avoid not only the redirect but also the forms authentication itself in order to make a web api work. Entries in web.config with a location tag for the api didn't help.
Thus I used SuppressFormAuthenticationRedirect and HttpContext.Current.SkipAuthorization to suppress the authentication in general.
In order to identify the sender I used e.g. the UserAgent in the Header but it is of course recommendable to implement further authentification steps, e.g. check against the sending IP or send another key with the request.
Below is inserted in the Global.asax.cs.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent == "SECRET-AGENT")
        {
            AppLog.Log("Redirect suppressed");

            HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;

            context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            HttpContext.Current.SkipAuthorization = true;                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect the user to Unauthorize Page rather than to the login page, the Hack is to implement Application_EndRequest in Global and check for Response Status Code 302, which is a temporary redirect from the current called to action.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode == 302 && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/UnauthorizedPageUrl");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Look inside your Web.config file in `configuration\authentication`.
If there is a `forms` subelement there with a `loginUrl` attribute, remove it and try again.

Comment: Removing that just changed the URL it redirects to `/login.aspx` instead of my custom one. I want to keep Forms Authentication for "normal" pages anyway, just for this one .ashx file I wanted to change it.