# HTTP Response Unauthorized redirects to login.aspx

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, rest

I'm newbie in web programming with C#, and developing WCF RESTful services for Mobile Applications.

In REST service class, I set up response code as HTTP 401 Unauthorized, but it redirects other page suddenly.

Here's my service code:

```
    [WebGet]
    public string login(string id, string password)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(id, password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(id, false);

            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return "Login Succeeded";
        }
        else
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return "Login Failed";
        }
    }
```

If login is succeeded, it works fine, but if I enter wrong password, this page redirects to

```
http://localhost:50195/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fuser%2flogin%3fid%3dtest74323%26password%3d535201&id=test74323&password=####
```

I thinks there's auto-redirecting to user login page configuration, how can I off that configuration? I think problem is complicated while I'm using form authentication in the service.

I'm using form authentication with login cookie, I know that is not RESTful way, but I can't help it due to integration with other services. (in-company matter, hh)

And if there's some not-wrong but better way to implement login service, please let me know.

How can I show better error message when I access service with web browser? I know there's nothing to return if login is succeeded, I thought I'd better show string value if client accesses with web browser.

Comment: In your configuration file is there an `authentication` section with login page for forms authentication?

Comment: nope. there is only form authentication provider. I thinks there's default configuration to redirect login.aspx, how can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer in the link below:

[Forms authentication: disable redirect to the login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839406/forms-authentication-disable-redirect-to-the-login-page)

There's many way to probe this situation, dirty-and-quick sorted hh

1. use other response code and change it at `EndRequest`
2. implement `HttpModule` and change redirect 302 code to unauthenticated 401 again.
3. don't use `FormsAuthenticationModule`, and re-implement your own `Application_AuthenticateRequest`

I choose 2. I think 1. is too dirty, 3. is too slow and big work.

Answer (score 0):

You can change default login url in authentication section as below:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I tried that option, but I can only set the where to redirect, it cannot be disabled. 